# How to get textboxs values if a checkbox is checked

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

I have created a page to generate invoices. I am getting products data from database using php. Now when I try to generate an invoice and select some product(s) using checkbox. It only give me values of selected checkbox which is "Product Name" but it is not giving me values of relevant checkboxs containing its price and quantity etc. Following is my code: -

```
   <?php 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from products order by product_name asc");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
$product_id = $row['product_id'];
$product_name = $row['product_name'];
echo "<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' name='product_id[]' value='$product_id'> $product_name</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='product_ref[]' class='form-control'></td>
    <td width='2%'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='form-control'></td>
    <td width='2%'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='unit_price[]' class='form-control'></td>
</tr>";
```

Comment: There is a lot of code in your post, consider cutting it down to create a minimal example with hard-coded data if need be.

Comment: See, this is code which is retrieving  products form database. When I try to select a particular product it is not giving me values of qty and unit price etc.

Comment: You completely ignored my comment, as though you never understood it.

Comment: <?php 
 $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from products order by product_name asc");
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
 {
 $product_id = $row['product_id'];
 $product_name = $row['product_name'];
 echo "<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='product_id[]' value='$product_id'> $product_name</td>
  <td><input type='text' name='product_ref[]' class='form-control'></td>
  <td width='2%'></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='form-control'></td>
  <td width='2%'></td>
  <td><input type='text' name='unit_price[]' class='form-control'></td>
 </tr>

Comment: Sorry I was posting small code here. But is not in proper code format.

Comment: Then you update your original post and add the code in.

Comment: I just edited the code and removed extra code. Can you please look into it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some way to associate your form inputs with the correct product upon submission.

Here's a possible approach using the product ids as keys:

```
<?php 
$products =
[
    [
        'id' => 'foo',
        'name' => 'Food Packs'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'bar',
        'name' => 'Bar Snacks'
    ]
];

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    foreach($products as $product)
    {
        $id       = $product['id'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$id] ?? null;
        $price    = $_POST['price'][$id]    ?? null;

        if($quantity && $price) {
            // DB INSERT HERE
            var_dump($id, $quantity, $price);
        }
    }
}

echo '<form method="post">';
foreach($products as $product)
{
    echo
    "<div>
        {$product['name']}<br />
        Quantity: <input type='text' name='quantity[{$product['id']}]'>
        Price:    <input type='text' name='price[{$product['id']}]'>
    </div>";
}
echo '<input type="submit"></form>';
```

For multiple inserts you might want to use and recycle a prepared statement. Your previously listed SQL is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from products order by product_name asc");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
    $product_name = $row['product_name'];
    echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='product_id[]' value='$product_id'> $product_name</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='product_ref[]' class='form-control'></td>
        <td width='2%'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='form-control'></td>
        <td width='2%'></td>
        <td><input type='text' name='unit_price[]' class='form-control'></td>
    </tr>";
```